# sshfs - howto view load and find bottlenecks

Tags: sshfs, diagnostic, bottleneck

I got 2 dirs mounted by sshfs from remove server. And suspect those make my app so slowly (app generate many i/o operations in this).
I can use fdisk/iostat/iotop for diagnostic HDDs bottlenecks, but sshfs mounts not shows in this tools. Where can i find this information?
Dirs mounted by

> sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/rsa-key-file root@server:/dir/ /dir/

Comment: `sshfs` is just slow. Do you have no other way of accomplishing your goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you can run your application on your own (e.g. restart it), you could try with strace:

```
strace -f ./myslowapplication
```

and see what it tries to read(3) or write(3) and where it spends time waiting. Hope this helps.